# Maltese gasps after eating fastly, is that something to worry about?

Tags: dogs, health, diseases

My dog always tends to eat his food really fast, and right after finishing he all of sudden starts to lose breath and does something like gasping. When it calms down this stops, but I find myself very worried about it.

Is this really a thing to worry about? I heard that this can be an issue with small dogs, but is there a way to deal with that?

Comment: What kind of food do you feed? Dry food, moist food, meat?

Comment: I mix of vegetables , meat and rice. i bought from a company that does natural food for dogs.

Comment: Is it processed into pallets or actual rice grains with veggies and meat? If it's pallets, you should moisten them before feeding, especially if they swell in water.

Comment: actual rice grains with veggies and meat, its like a pre made food for us, but for dogs. We heat it in the microwave (other subject that im doubt if its good for them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like he may be eating so quickly that he chokes on his food. If this is the case, try feeding him smaller amounts at a time. Instead of giving him his entire bowl at once, give him a couple mouthfuls at a time and make sure he's gotten them down before giving him more. This will make sure he eats more slowly and carefully.

Alternatively, you mentioned you heat his food. You might be making it too hot for him. Try letting it thaw to room temperature rather than heating it and see if that helps.

Comment: You can also try purchasing a slow feeder; they have nubs and grooves that force your dog to lick up the food instead of gulping/chomping at it!